# How to check the previous selected radio button if an user doesn't accept JS confirm message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and jquery-rails-2.0.2. In a my form I have many radio buttons and I would like to check the previous selected radio button if an user doesn't accept a confirm message. I think I may implement something like the following

```
<%= form.radio_button(:name_1, 'value_1', { :onclick => ('selectRadio(this)') }) %>
<%= form.radio_button(:name_2, 'value_2', { :onclick => ('selectRadio(this)') }) %>
<%= # Other radio buttons %>
<%= form.radio_button(:name_n, 'value_n', { :onclick => ('selectRadio(this)') }) %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectRadio(radiobutton) {
    var confirm_message = confirm('Are you sure?');

    if (confirm_message) {
      # Check the selected radio button.
    } else {
      # Re-check the previous selected radio button.
    }
  }
</script>
```

... but I have no solution to "re-check the previous selected radio button". *Is it possible? If so, how to make that?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code block to do this

I am assuming all your considering radio buttons has a common class, like `radios`

```
var prev = $(".radios:checked");

$(".radios").change(function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')){ 
           prev = $(this); 
    }else{
           prev.prop('checked','checked');   
    }    
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/PgEkA/5/)

Reference: [$.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)  [$.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store user's choice when they check, and revert it back if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // first get checked radio button where myform is your form in which radiobuttons reside  
   var lastRadio = $("#myform input[type='radio']:checked");
   function selectRadio(radiobutton) {
      var confirm_message = confirm('Are you sure?');
      if (confirm_message) {
         lastRadio = $(radiobutton);
         # Check the selected radio button.
      } else {
         lastRadio.attr('checked',true);
         # Re-check the previous selected radio button.
      }
    }
</script>
```